# Relate two columns in the same table

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a MySQL query which should count the amount of replies to your comments with relations to other columns.

I try to "relate" two columns together but can't figure out how to create a correct query.

The table somewhat looks like this:

| author_id | content | comment_id | replied_to |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | nice post! | 1 | 0 |
| 7 | isn't it? | 2 | 1 |
| 12 | for sure | 3 | 2 |
| 4 | i didn't like it so much | 4 | 0 |
| 7 | why is that? | 5 | 4 |
| 11 | please elaborate | 6 | 4 |

So to know how many replies **you** have, we need to relate replied_to and comment_id. But also we need to determine the relation between the comment_id and to whom it belongs to.

Let's assume that I am a user with author_id 4 and two people replied to my comment which are the comment_id 5 and 6. The query should return 2.

I've tried something like this (this is an incorrect query, since you can't do something like comment_id.author_id = 4):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM comments WHERE replied_to = comment_id AND comment_id.author_id = 4;
```

How to approach this kind of query, or is the table structure incorrectly done and should be in another table instead?

Comment: Can you update your post with the expected output?

Comment: @lemon The expected output should be 2 as I state above. I'm counting the amount of replies made to you.

Comment: Did you try just `WHERE replied_to = 4`?

Comment: @forpas yes, this is the first thing I've tried and realized it isn't just that simple. Now the replied_to = 4 would reference to a comment_id 4, not author_id 4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a self-join can help in situations like this.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count
FROM comments AS post
JOIN comments AS reply ON reply.replied_to = post.comment_id 
WHERE post.author_id = 4;
```

Comment: Great, this partially worked after I removed the first "AS" keyword from the first line. However now it returns list of comment_id's with the count next to it. I'm trying to count all of these in total.

Comment: Sorry about the dangling "AS". I meant to give that column an alias. I fixed it now.

Comment: I edited to fix the grouping. I misunderstood that you wanted the total replies, not subtotal per post.

Comment: It's totally fine, now it work just as intended. Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 1):

Use the operator `IN` with a subquery in the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM comments 
WHERE replied_to IN (SELECT comment_id FROM comments WHERE author_id = 4);
```

Comment: This worked too. Is there any performance difference between IN and the self-join that is down below?

Comment: @Timppa they seem identical: https://dbfiddle.uk/7M1XTyCK

Comment: I seem to recall that you might get more efficient results if you do a COUNT(author_id) instead of counting ALL the things?

Comment: @easleyfixed *counting ALL the things* is what is needed here. The requirement is to count all the comments. `COUNT(author_id)` would make no difference because in all the counted rows `author_id` is not null.

Comment: I could of sworn there was a WHERE on the end of that which would of specified to only look at the ones that meet the criteria, but you might be right on that.